# Singleton with params

Tags: java, parameters, singleton

I've write a Singleton, but this singleton need a Context as a param to initialize itself. As the Context is used only once in its constructor, I would not like to add it in getInstance(Context). After thinking more, I came out the following answer:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Context sContext;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        sContext = context;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
        if (sContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("#init should be called in Application#onCreate");
        }
        // Initialize the Singleton.
        // .....
        // After the constructed, remove the sContext.
        sContext = null;
    }
}
```

It's well, with a class method init called in Android/Applicaiton#onCreate method.
It's not instance the SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, as it's not loaded.
Could some give someone advice on my solution。Thanks！

With the help of @ WarrenFaith I changed my code.

```
 public class Singleton {

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
        final Context context = BaseApplication.getApplication();
        // Initialize the Singleton.
        // .....
    }
}

public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    private static Application sApplication;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return sApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sApplication = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a way easier solution:

```
public class Singleton {
    private final static Singleton mInstance = new Singleton();
    private final static Context sContext;

    private Singleton() {
        sContext = MyApplication.getInstance();
        // do more
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

That is a pretty bullet proof singleton pattern.

Of course you need to implement your application class to be a singleton but by definition it already is.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        // create your Singleton!
        Singleton.getInstance();
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I know your solution. I'm not like to load the Singleton when the Singleton static util method is called. So I need to push the instance of Singleton until the first time the getInstance is called or SingltonHolder.INSTANCE is invoked. We know MyApplication.getInstance() should set a static INSTANCE object in #onCreate. They are worked the same. There are many flaws for Application static INSTANCE.

Comment: I don't get your issue. You do not need to call the singleton.getInstance in onCreate of application. That was just a sample. All you need to make sure is that it is called *after* the mInstance of the application is set. The rest works flawless. What do you mean by "flaws for Application static instance"?

Comment: FirstBefore, I was not quite sure that whether the application is a singleton or not.

Comment: I'll do it later after I got 15 reputations. -_-|||